# Change URL of Bookmark when user Bookmarks page

Tags: javascript, php, browser, bookmarks

I'm trying to change the URL of a bookmark so that when the user bookmarks a page, it actually bookmarks a different URL that the user must pass through first. Is that possible with javascript or any other languages?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do what you want since bookmarking is typically handled the browser and doesn't involve the page being viewed (beyond its name and URL, I mean).

Comment: What do you try to achieve? Can you elaborate this a bit more?

Comment: Is there a reason you want them to pass through a certain URL?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well you can try to hijack the `Ctrl+D` command to bookmark.

Anything farther than that is not really feasible since bookmarking is usually handled by the browser and not the website.

Comment: Any idea of how I would hijack it? That's exactly what I'm looking to do.

Comment: @Ed just check what buttons are pressed and you can go from there...

Comment: Would this would work if the user bookmarked using the browser controls (Bookmarks > Bookmark this page, etc.)?

Comment: @Neal - thanks. I just threw in some javascript to check for when ctrl and d are pressed and made a bookmark simulation. That should work for what I need. If the user uses browser controls, they'll just have to live :) Thanks!

Comment: This is not a good idea, you're site will be considered to be taking over the browser.

Comment: @timw4mail. i never said it was a good or bad idea. also that is why i used the work `hijack` ^_^, but it does answer the OP's question so im not sure why the downvote

Answer (score 3):

No. Bookmarking is a functionality implemented in the browser, the HTTP client. It will bookmark what the user commands the browser to do. This almost always in all browsers is the URL displayed in the address field.

So it is normally not possible within a browser to manipulate the storage of the bookmark.

However depending on what you try to achieve, your application can provide URLs that only work for a fraction of time. If bookmarked and that amount of time has passed, your application does know that this is an older, hence assumable a bookmarked URL. You can then make your application react to that, offering an additional page a user must pass through.

This can be done with some sort of session as well, and combined with referrer checking.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't change a user's bookmark, but you can make sure the user gets to the new page by doing a proper 301 redirect.

Comment: Technically a proper 303 redirect.

Comment: 303 redirects are supposed to be temporary, I meant a 301 redirect, which is permanent